# Asp.net identity extra user information like email etc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am using new ASP.NET Identity. I have added some extra user information like email, mobile etc, but at the time of user creation I am getting the following exception:

> An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.
>
> Inner exception:
>
> {"Invalid column name 'Discriminator'.\r\nInvalid column name 'FirstName'.\r\nInvalid column name 'LastName'.\r\nInvalid column name 'DateOfBirth'.\r\nInvalid column name 'Age'.\r\nInvalid column name 'Mobile'."}

**Code:**

`AccountController`

```
            var user = new ApplicationUser()
            {
                UserName = model.Email,
                DateOfBirth = model.DateOfBirth,
                FirstName = model.FirstName,
                LastName = model.LastName,
                Mobile = model.Mobile,
                Age = model.Age
            };

            var result = UserManager.Create(user, model.Password); //exception
```

`Model`:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().Property(p => p.DateOfBirth).HasColumnType("datetime2");

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong ??

Comment: Check to which table your values are inserted and it matches with your passes values

Comment: What does your viewmodel look like? Where is the error thrown? When?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The displays the mismatch in the Code Model and Database.

Verify you have migrated the changes before running application. Use following commands appropriately.

- Add-Migration
- Update-Database

Also make sure to provide appropriate DatabaseMigration Strategy at the start. For example,

`Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>(new System.Data.Entity.MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<ApplicationDbContext, Configuration>());`